# OOM and Servlet Containers

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is there any Servlet Container / J2EE Application Server can run context in its own java proccess so it won't bring down all contexts+virtual hosts in case of OOM failure.
Recently I had an tomcat application which failed with OOM because of some guy's context within webapps.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but you might find this interesting: http://serverfault.com/questions/130229/multiple-java-apps-on-single-server

Comment: Tomcat is not really industrial strength anyway. For any heavy JEE lifting, a proper JEE container is recommended: glassfish, jboss etc

Comment: jboss can handle if one context / virtual host triggers OOM ? or it will crash ?